# How to make the TQDM progress bar update automatically between KB and MB

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, tqdm

I have a simple `tqdm` bar integrated with `requests` module to download files, code:

```py
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm

def download_to_file(path: str, filename: str, url: str):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        file_length = int(r.headers['Content-Length'])
        chunk_size = 1024  # 1MB
        num_bars = int(file_length / chunk_size)

        if r.status_code == 200:
            with open(f'{path}\\{filename}', 'wb+') as f:
                pbar = tqdm(total=num_bars, unit='B', unit_scale=True, desc=filename, leave=False, file=sys.stdout,
                            unit_divisor=1024)
                for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
                    if chunk:
                        pbar.update()
                        f.write(chunk)
        else:
            raise requests.HTTPError(f'Status code is {r.status_code}')
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f'[-] Failed to download \'{filename}\'! {str(ex)}')
        pass
```

It works but this is the progress bar `file.extension: 100%|████████████▉| 123k/123k [00:58<00:00, 2.87kB/s]`, the problem is the 123MB file is shown as 123k and the current speed is shown in KB/s, I tried changing the unit to KB instead but then it just makes the speed go to 2.87kKB/s which should be MB/s.
I tried looking into GitHub repositories that I know use tqdm but couldn't find an example of what I want to do, how do I make it show 123MB in the total size and the speed start at KB/s but then change to MB/s when it goes over 1000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is prerry old, but i've just needed to do that same.
I used `pbar = tqdm(total=num_bars, unit="bytes", unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1024)` for my progress bar and the result of it is
 `3%|▎         | 9.00M/282M [00:02<01:01, 4.69Mbytes/s]` (This file size is correct)
So I guess that you shouldn't divide `file_length` by `chunk_size`, as the `total` is the number of expected iterations and tqdm will automatically adjust the unit

I hope that you or the next person will find this useful

Comment: Sorry but what is the difference with what OP posted ? I guess in num_bars you put the file_length, but that will yield an incorrect loading bar if you load into chunks of 1000 bytes, since you would tell tqdm you need 1000 times as much iterations.

Comment: The difference is that `file_length` wasn't divided by `chunk_size` for `num_bars`, as i've written "the `total` is the number of expected iterations and tqdm will automatically adjust the unit"

Comment: If you load by chunks of "chunk_size", then the expected number of iterations is precisely file_length/chunk_size. If you provide file_length as the total number of iterations, then it will be wront by a factor of chunk_size, providing a wrong loading bar. Is there something I am missing ? The file size will be correct of course, but it will expect to do 1000 more iteration than needed, in the case where chunk_size=1000